# Does the gRPC support ASYNCHRONOUS SERVER as well as asynchronous client by server-side callback-like mechanism?

Tags: asynchronous, server, callback, grpc

This is not about asynchronous client-to-server call.
It's about a gRPC server programming model. To maximize the gRPC server throughput, it's desired that a gRPC server delegates received requests to non-gRPC threads with a callback for each request. When non-gRPC threads get things done, they inform the gRPC server to response gRPC clients by calling equipped callbacks for these asynchronously handled requests.
Is this possible for grpc? I noticed there is an experimental feature about callback mechanism. However, an experimental feature is not a choice for my projects.

Or, in another words, 
1) how could a gRPC server thread not be blocked by time-consuming request handling?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ server has two threading models available: sync and async. Most users will want to use the sync model: the server will have an (internal) threadpool that manages multiplexing requests onto some number of threads (reusing threads between requests). The async model allows you to bring your own threading model, but is a little trickier to use - in that mode you request new calls when your server is ready for them, and block in completion queues while there is no work to do. By arranging when you block on the completion queues, and on which completion queues you make requests, you can arrange a wide variety of threading models.

https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/Cul6fd7cOB0/m/c5gndkNpGQAJ has detailed discussion about both sync/async server models.